# how to find out the distribution of an event

Tags: probability

I wrote a computer program that can predict the position of a particle based on its movement history, and of course with some error. Now I'm keen to find the distribution of the error to judge the performance of the program. So, I want to know how can I calculate how many trials I should take to get a "good" distribution. From memory, this should depend on the confidence level I'm aiming to get and the size of bins in my final distribution as a histogram. Also, the final distribution might also be skewed due to the problem and it might need to be taken into account.

Any idea how should I proceed?
Any references or keywords for further study are also appreciated.

Thank you very much!

p.s. I drew a histogram of first 700 runs, which might be helpful...

[image: histogram of 700 error outputs]

Comment: This is far too vague to give meaningful answers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, what other information should I add?

Comment: Actual details about what you've done? So we can do math?

Comment: You need to provide the algorithm that predicts position (some kind of difference scheme?) and also specify what you mean by error.

Comment: Hello Paul ans Don, the algorithm is a little hard to explain, basically I have a math model for the history of particle position so I can trace back its theoretical path. So I use optimization routines so see at which guess position can produce a theoretical history path that is most similar to the existing history path I have. The "error" is the distance between particle I used to generate history and the particle I predicted.

Comment: I've uploaded a histogram of the distance between them in z direction for 700 runs, hope that will help. Oh, and the optimization routine I used is L-BFGS-B provided by scipy.

Comment: Without knowing the details all one can offer you is to generate the a large sample of the errors and then you can estimate the empirical CDF as usual. That is compute $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\epsilon_k \leq x}$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you for the reply. I wonder is there any way to estimate what sample size I need? For example, if I want the mean to be in a certain interval with a certain confidence level, I need at least this number of samples? Or without a distribution model that is not possible?

Comment: @StillLearning... this should be a new question, really since it is much more specific. Anyway, you could start with assuming the errors are IID and appeal to the CLT on the sample mean. Then the usual approach to find a confidence interval of the error on the sample mean from true mean given sample size and/or necessary sample size given a CI works. If you want details, do some research (this is covered on wikipedia and almost any good book, e.g. Probability and Stochastic processes by F. Solomon ) or ask a new question with this specifically as your problem (likely a duplicate however...)

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you very much for the guidance, I’ll have a read about the book and open a new question if I can’t understand anything.